# WSO2 Identity Server - kerberos config

Tags: configuration, wso2, kerberos, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to activate the kerberos KDC on a WSO2 Identity Server, I'm following this tutorial:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/FAQ#FAQ-HowcanIsetupWSO2ISasaKDC?
The thing is that I can activate the Kerberos KDC, but I can't find this option in the management console.

```
Now login thorough management console and go to Configure -> Kerberos KDC -> Service Principals. You can see that "Add new service principals" option is now enabled and you'll be able to add service principals through that option.
```

Anyone has the same problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems that is not available in UI.

Comment: So... What can i do? The console which you use to start the server it's only to read logs (on Windows)....
Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you create a public jira?

Comment: I have an instance on AWS and I can. But I haven't ever used JIRA, I only know that's to make dashboards, right? 0 idea about the rest of Jira, I'm sorry.
Thanks for your patience.
If you prefer talking to me by email-> d.baus@outlook.com