# WSO2 KDC Config not appearing

Tags: wso2, kerberos

I am trying to set up WSO Identity Server as a Kerberos KDC. The instructions are clear and simple, basically change two config entries and then you should see "Kerberos server started" in the log when starting up.

Did that, see the success message, but the next step is to configure service principals in the UI, however none of the KDC config options appear. I have now tried this with two different versions of WSO2 IS (5.1.0 and 5.3.0), on two different machines (both OSX though).

I am aware that [this question has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36059590/wso2-identity-server-kerberos-config), but there was no resolution, although the person who asked it must have resolved the problem because they later posted other questions about WSO2 and Kerberos.

Comment: What about using the **standard** Kerberos configuration, in `/etc/krb5.conf` (default location in in Linux, hopefully OSX honors that default...)

Comment: The documentation is available at https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.15/doc/admin/conf_files/krb5_conf.html

Comment: krb5.conf is for the client config, I'm talking about the server. I also need LDAP and OpenID Connect, so I was looking for an all-in-one solution. I might have a look at krb5kdc though.

Comment: Right. Quoting the documentation _"WSO2 Identity Server uses an ApacheDS-based LDAP server user store. It also has an **ApacheDS based KDC implementation**. "_ Then quoting the Apache Directory documentation at http://directory.apache.org/kerby/user-guide/1-how-to-begin.html _"In [server-conf-dir], there should be **kdc.conf**, **backend.conf**"_ Now you can go back to the MIT Kerberos documentation about these config files.

Comment: Thanks. I spent two days trying to get ApacheDS to work (absolutely terrible documentation e.g. http://directory.apache.org/apacheds/kerberos-ug/2.3-kerberos-server-config.html) before I gave up and installed WSO2, believing the hype that it was simple to install.

Strange that in the WSO2 Kerberos documentation (https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/FAQ, look for "How can I setup WSO2 IS as a KDC?") it only says you need to change two config entries and doesn't mention ApacheDS or MIT settings.

Where did you find that?

Comment: Disclaimer: I never used ApacheDS nor WSO2. My guess is that WSO2 makes it easier to _install_ the KDC, but you still have to configure Kerberos stuff by yourself. And _every_ KDC implementation in the *nix world appears to use the same config file syntax... which is best documented by MIT.

Comment: For what it's worth, see the comment at bottom of http://kerberos.mit.narkive.com/XgjhkBsR/apacheds-kerberos-server

Comment: Thanks again, but the WSO2 log says the Kerberos service is started, with no other errors or warnings. I would expect that if key config files were missing it should say something, and I would also expect the WSO2 doco to point out all the necessary steps. 

I was actually just hoping that user @dbaus might be able to tell me how they solved this problem. Otherwise I'll just ditch it and try the MIT one.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry that sounds I am a bit late.

I have just run into exactly the same issue and managed to "solve" it.

**Simply by hardcoding the link http://yourhost/carbon/servicestore/index.jsp will bring you there.**
[Like the example here, I can access the Service Principal page even without the UI link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g215j.png)
FYI I am using IS-5.3.0.

Comment: Updated. Thank you for your advice.